# python - unitest setUp tearDown in different contexts

Tags: python, unit-testing

Deo python support setUp() and tearDown() acts differently depending on the context? By all means, I am asking about if I can do something like this:

```
setUp() {
    if(context1){
         do A;
    }
    else{
         do B;
    }
}


tearDown() {
    if(context1){
         do A;
    }
    else{
         do B;
    }
}
```

Comment: There would probably be more answers if you posted *Python* code.

Comment: you can do that, having the context as a global variable or a class variable that is set in `setUpClass()` that's called once before each test. but the point of fixtures is to provide the context. if you need that you probably need two tests, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, and just like you show it: use if blocks and only do particular parts of the setup if the condition is true.

I think what you're getting at is to have different versions of `setUp` and `tearDown` for different tests. I'd actually suggest that you either:

- split the tests into different TestCase subclasses with the proper `setUp`/`tearDown` methods
- or don't use `setUp` and `tearDown` at all - do something like this

  ```
  class MyTestCase:
      def _setup_for_foo_tests():
          # blah blah blah
      def _setup_for_bar_tests():
          # blah blah blah
      def test_foo_1():
          self._setup_for_foo_tests()
          # test code
      def test_foo_2():
          self._setup_for_foo_tests()
          # test code
      def test_bar_1():
          self._setup_for_bar_tests()
          # test code
      # etc etc etc
  ```

Comment: what about tearDown, suppose you created a bunch of test files in setup, you need to write _teardown_for_foo_tests as well? @AdamKG

Comment: Yup, that's right. There's a great talk [here](http://pyvideo.org/video/634/speedily-practical-large-scale-tests) that goes into this technique - the underlying goal is to explicitly call the setup/teardown code a test depends on instead of implicitly expecting setUp/tearDown to be called, since it can then become difficult to tell if there's unnecessary (and potentially time-consuming) code running for a given test.

Answer (score 2):

You should think about doing 2 different classes (maybe with some a common ancestor) of test for each context of test you need, it would be easier.

Something like this :

```
class BaseTest():
    def test_01a(self):
        pass

class Context1TestCase(BaseTest, unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # do what you need for context1

    def tearDown(self):
        # do what you need for context1

class Context2TestCase(BaseTest, unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # do what you need for context2

    def tearDown(self):
        # do what you need for context2
```

this way, `test_01a` will be executed once in context1, once in context2.